# Using Array with Osmosis

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm making an iOS app and I am trying to use [Osmosis](https://github.com/ChristianPraiss/Osmosis) to fetch some data from a website and display it in my app. In order to do that, I am following the [usage](https://github.com/ChristianPraiss/Osmosis#usage) as it is described in the readme file on github.

My problem is that I get an error when trying to get the parsed information. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var array: [String] = []
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Osmosis(errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
            print(error)
        })
            .get(NSURL(string: "www.mysite.com")!)
            .find(OsmosisSelector(selector: ".quote"), type: .CSS)
            .populate([
                    OsmosisPopulateKey.Single("quotes") : OsmosisSelector(selector: "tt_quotes b")
                ], type: .CSS)
            .list { (dict) -> Void in
                self.array.append(dict)
            .start()
        print(dict)
```

When I try to build my project, I get the following error:

`ViewController.swift:34:35: Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]' to expected argument type 'String'`

Why does my project crash and how should I declare my array in order to make it work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare your array to hold `String` objects here:

```
var array: [String] = []
```

If you want it to hold dictionaries, change the declaration to:

```
var array: [[String : AnyObject]] = []
```

or use `[AnyObject]` to hold any types of objects (Strings, Dictionaries, whatever).

For your second issue, you don't close your closure:

```
.list { (dict) -> Void in
    self.array.append(dict)
}.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I do that, I get the following error:

`ViewController.swift:34:28: Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'start'`

Comment: @Mehdi edited my answer to address your second question.